# Copying contents of a file using pipe() and fork()

Tags: c, linux

Similar questions has already been asked, but their solutions aren't helping me much

[Program that read file and send it to parent process with pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10139470/program-that-read-file-and-send-it-to-parent-process-with-pipe)

[Read/writing on a pipe, accomplishing file copying in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14983451/read-writing-on-a-pipe-accomplishing-file-copying-in-c)

---

I'm trying to read from a file `test.txt` ( which contains a single line of text), write it to a pipe, from where a child process will read from the pipe and write the contents to another file.

```
 /* Read the contents of a file and display it using pipe */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
  char buffer[100];
  char childbuff[100];
  int fd[2], des, bytes, target;

  pipe(fd);

  if(fork()) {
    /* parent process closes the downstream */
    close(fd[0]);

    /* reads the file */
    des = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY);
    bytes = read(des, buffer, sizeof(buffer));

    /* puts data in pipe */
    write(fd[1], buffer, bytes);
  } else {
    /* Child process closes the upstream */
    close(fd[1]);

    /* reads from the pipe */
    read(fd[0], childbuff, sizeof(childbuff));
    close(fd[0]);

    /* output the received string */
    printf("\nReceived string is -- %s", childbuff);
    target = open("copy.txt", O_CREAT, 00777);
    write(target, childbuff, (strlen(childbuff)-1));
  }
}
```

Problem is `printf()` prints the string on terminal, a file named `copy.txt` also gets created, but nothing is getting copied to it (it seems there is a problem with the `write()` function )

however, if I change

```
write(target, childbuff, (strlen(childbuff)-1));
```

to

```
write(1, childbuff, (strlen(childbuff)-1));
```

string is simply getting written on my terminal.

So what possibly am I doing wrong while writing to file?

Comment: Unrelated: you do not need 2 separate buffers, but you should check if `fork()` returns `-1` indicating failure to fork a child process.

Comment: @chqrlie if I use a single buffer, will I have to clear the buffer after parent writes it to pipe? Can you show me how to do that using single buffer?

Comment: No, after a successful `fork()` syscall, each process, parent and child, has its own copy of the data, global and automatic.  The `buffer` array of the parent process is separate from the `buffer` array of the child process.

Comment: @chqrlie will keep that in mind. thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You also need `O_WRONLY` to write to the file:

```
target = open("copy.txt", O_CREAT |O_WRONLY, 00777);
```

Note that you can't use `strlen()` or `%s` to print it as a C-string. `read(2)` doesn't return a NUL terminated string.

Instead get the number of bytes read from `read()` and use it in `write()`:

```
    ssize_t num_bytes = read(fd[0], childbuff, sizeof(childbuff));

    write(target, childbuff, num_bytes);
```

You should check the return of *all* system calls for failure.

Comment: Thank You. Solved my problem :)

Comment: Is it possible to copy from the origin file to destination where the length of the input file is not know. I mean, is it possible to transfer the content in multiple steps of size equal to the capacity of the buffer

Comment: @AbhayPatil Of course, you can. You can use a loop to achieve that.

Comment: @P.P we will call wait in the parent process and in the child in each iteration we will read the content into the buffer and put it into the pipe and then after the wait, in parent similarly take it out in iterations. Is this the way to go?

Comment: @AbhayPatil I've modified the code in question. See https://ideone.com/2pppyU

Comment: @P.P Thanks. I had already implemented this in some other way, but yours is way better than mine. Thanks again.